# Corda MQ node error - Message for incorrect endpoint using a p2pAddress hostname

Tags: corda

I'm running Corda 3.1, and running nodes on separate machines.  If I specify my p2pAddress as my hostname, after successful startup, I receive a Message for incorrect endpoint error when attempting transactions in the IOU example:

```
[ERROR] 2018-05-31T14:48:22,406Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] O=Bank A,L=London,C=GB.write - Error in AMQP write processing {}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Message for incorrect endpoint
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.protonwrapper.netty.AMQPChannelHandler.write(AMQPChannelHandler.kt:124) [corda-node-api-3.1-corda.jar:?]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:738) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:730) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1089) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1136) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1078) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144) [netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Here is the snippet of my node.conf:

```
myLegalName : "O=Bank A,L=London,C=GB"
p2pAddress : "my-load-balancer-hostname.aws.com:10002"
rpcSettings = {
    address : "localhost:10003"
    adminAddress : "localhost:10004"
}
rpcUsers : [
    { username=user1, password=test, permissions=[ ALL ] }
]
devMode : true
```

I can resolve this (and make transactions across nodes as expected) by using the IP address of the machine as the p2pAddress.  However, my node IP could change, thus I'd like to use the hostname?  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you correctly updating the `additional-node-infos` of the other nodes?

Comment: No, I thought I didn't need to if I was using a Network Map.  I'm just running the corda.jar from each node and specifying a compatibilityZoneURL using this network map service (https://github.com/roastario/spring-boot-network-map).  Is that the right approach or if I should be copying the node-infos around..?

Comment: Ah ok, so this might be an issue with that specific network map. Let me investigate :)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to the AWS load balancer.

Comment: Sorry, thanks.  My mistake, I missed copying in the port number, it should be there.  `p2pAddress : "my-load-balancer-hostname.aws.com:10002"`

Comment: Curious if this has something to do with the AWS load balancer.  Will look more this morning...

Comment: Hi, Currently facing same issue which you had. Any solution you found?

Answer (score 0):

Did some further debugging on this and discovered the root cause.

The error was thrown from AMQPChannelHandler.kt, line 148, when doing validation for the AMQ destination:

```
require(inetAddress == remoteAddress) { "Message for incorrect endpoint" }
```

The InetSocketAddress.java equality returns false because the IP changes. Debugging properties:

```
inetAddress.hostString: party-corda-node-dev.aws.co.com,
inetAddress.address: party-corda-node-dev.aws.co.com/10.224.8.233     
inetAddress.port: 10002
inetAddress.isUnresolved: false

remoteAddress.hostString: liberty-corda-node-dev.aws.co.com
remoteAddress.address: liberty-corda-node-dev.aws.co.com/10.224.10.46
remoteAddress.port: 10002
remoteAddress.isUnresolved: false
```

Suggested fix to remove that validation check against resolved hostnames.

Documented in pull request https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3381